# angular looping json object and filtering data

Tags: arrays, json, angular, typescript, http

my angular application will recive  object's from backend

```
{
    "count": 6,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 160,
            "title": null,
            "rate": 5,
            "author": "anonymous",
            "content": null,
            "review": "here is the review",
            "url": "https://blog.com/?p=198",
            "fake": true,
            "tags": [
                "thi"
            ],
            "comments": [],
            "created_at": "2020-06-13T20:24:32.434131Z",
            "advertisement": {
                "id": 55,
                "created_at": "2020-06-13T20:24:32.432084Z",
                "title": null,
                "url": null,
                "advertizing_content": null
            }
        },
```

JSON data structure from backend
i have converted array

```
var dat:any=JSON.stringify(backenddata);
     this.z = backenddata["results"][0];
```

and seleted results

```
 {
                "id": 160,
                "title": null,
                "rate": 5,
                "author": "anonymous",
                "content": null,
                "review": "here is the review",
                "url": "https://blog.com/?p=198",
                "fake": true,
                "tags": [
                    "thi"
                ],
                "comments": [],
                "created_at": "2020-06-13T20:24:32.434131Z",
                "advertisement": {
                    "id": 55,
                    "created_at": "2020-06-13T20:24:32.432084Z",
                    "title": null,
                    "url": null,
                    "advertizing_content": null
                }
            },
```

i want to fetch all the tags in every object

```
console.log(this.z.tags)
```

i just got "undefined" in console

I tried

```
Object.values(tags);
```

i tried everything regarding this objects part 
objects.values,keys and all 
when i tried 
console.log(object.values(y)[8]);(y here is the json object)
i'm just getting a value of  first object's tag 
i want to loop all the objects segregate those tags and save it in variable

refereed many stack overflow thread's but its of no use
i have no clue what exactly is wrong 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=23ZjKQL-2E4&t=509s

also tried this tutorial
still its of no use

i just want to fetch all the tags of every object of thatjson response and save it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need `tags` from all the objects of the `results` array, you could use the [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function. Try the following

```js
tags = [];

this.someService.getData().subscribe(
  data => {
    this.tags = data['results'].map(result => result['tags']);
    // this.tags = [['thi'], ['thi', 'ths'], ...]
  },
  error => { }
);
```